# Another issue with Rspec's should_receive in model testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I'm trying to use Rspec for the first time to test a model on my app, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm using FactoryGirl to create the instances of the model.  Here is my spec:

```
describe 'adding a model instance' do
    before :each do
        @fake = FactoryGirl.create :user
    end

    it 'should add a new user to the database' do
        User.should_receive(:create).with(@fake).and_recieve@fake)
    end

end
```

Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :username, :name, :email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation, :bio
has_many :comments #comments user has posted on ideas
has_many :commented_ideas, :class_name => 'Idea', :through => :comments #ideas user has commented on
has_many :ideas #ideas user has posted

validates :password, :email, :confirmation => true
validates :username, :email, :password, :name, :presence => true
# validates :username, :email, :unique => true
end
```

and the error that I am getting:

```
Failure/Error: User.should_receive(:create!).with('username' => 'testUser', 'user_id' => "1").and_return(true)
   (<User(id: integer, username: string, name: string, email: string, password: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, bio: text) (class)>).create!({"username"=>"testUser", "user_id"=>"1"})
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User#create` isn't called anywhere in your code, hence the unmet expection. I think your misunderstanding is due to confusing the real class with the factory. I don't know what FactoryGirl does internally to create records, but it seems it's not a #create.